# Parents going though medical issues and possibility of expediting I-130

Tags: usa, visa, immigration

My parents and I are naturalized U.S. citizens, living in the U.S. for the past 15 years. However, I have two much older siblings who are married and have kids but are not U.S. citizens and do not live in the U.S. We applied for the [I-130 form](https://www.uscis.gov/i-130) for them about 6 years ago, and we have a case number, but the process may take years.

Recently my parents, who are both 75+, are going through major medical problems, and having their kids near them would greatly help with day-to-day tasks. I work at FAANG, and I had to ask to work remotely to help with my parents.

I am wondering is there a way to expedite my siblings' I-130 visa applications or bring my brother to the U.S. to help. He applied for a student visa at the university in the city where we live, but his visa was rejected because of [214(b)](https://visarefusal.com/214b/). I am not sure what options we have at this point.

Comment: This question belongs on [Expatriates.SE].

Comment: Going the other way around (parents go to siblings home country) is likely to be much faster

Comment: @JonathanReez there is no healthcare there